# I want to stack two DIVs on top of each other and have one be transparent so you can see through to the div behind it. Using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a background image inside a div and I want to be able to place another black box on top of the background image with a lower opacity so that you can see through it and it will darken the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` on an image in a container to push it to the back of the `div` to act as a `background-image` by giving it a z-index of -1 and the parent a z-index of 1. Then position it absolute and use it to fill the whole parent.

An implementation is here below:

**My `index.html` **

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="./images/img.jpg" alt="">
        <h1>My content</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My `style.css` **

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container .content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #00000052;
}
.container img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this effect is by applying the [CSS brightness filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness()) directly on the image.

You could certainly stack two divs on top of each other with absolute/relative positioning and z-index, but those can create [other issues](https://ishadeed.com/article/less-absolute-positioning-modern-css/) and will require you to write more code for less performance.

```css
.dark {
  filter: brightness(40%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" />

<img class="dark" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/68.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
```